# chkdsk asking to dismount volume, is that safe?

Tags: windows

I moved a hard drive into a new system and im receiving a blue screen that says new hard is causing an error ... And to run chkdsk. Upon running chkdsk from the recovery screen its asking to dismount the volume ( assuming c: ) is it wise to say Y or N... I don't want to be locked out of the c: and not being able to remount of things go wrong.

Comment: Windows 7 recovery?

Comment: Yes, win7 recovery. Is it safe to say Y? If I say no it gives the option to run on restart but unfortunately that doesn't happen since the blue screen is shown first.

Comment: the dis-mount of a partition/disk is so it can do the checks and any changes without any locks on the drive. I find that normally this is a **temporary** dismount. If it cannot dismount and do the checks then it still can do it at boot. When asking is it "safe" it is safe to dismount.  This does not include it always being safe to chkdsk a drive that might have other issues :-) or been part of a split raid or a file system that is completly misunderstood by the chkdsk.  Making the dismount fine, not guarenteeing that chkdsk itself is perfect in all situations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's safe, nothing bad will happen (Recovery itself should be running from **X:**). Unless the other disk is so damaged (platter surface or head assembly), that running **chkdsk** will only make it worse. I think you deliberately need to specify the **volume** on the disk, though. Otherwise why would it ask to dismount **C:**? What I mean is: **chkdsk /R D:**, if D: is the drive you've inserted into the system. Can be checked by **diskpart** - **list volume**.

Comment: Okay, its running... Fingers crossed... Will report back when it's complete

Comment: @acctman It should be done by now. Did it work? :)

Comment: Looking his profile and his answer to another question, I think he couldn't make it using this way but somehow he did it @BranislavKollár :)